# How to connect JNativeHook to JavaFX Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm making a translator program that has a gui in Javafx.  I am using JNativeHook to enable global keylisteners for when the app is not in focus.  When alt and t are pressed at the same time, the program is supposed to restore itself from the taskbar.

However, when i press alt and t, it get an error saying the JNativeHook thread cannot run with the javafx thread.

Is it even possible to have the GlobalScreen thread communicate with the javafx thread?

This is my Global keylistener code

```
GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(listener);
```

and this is my listener

```
                @Override
                public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {
                    if(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_ALT_L){
                        alt = true;
                    }
                    if(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_T){
                        t = true;
                    }

                    check();

                }

                @Override
                public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {
                    if(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_ALT_L){
                        alt = false;
                    }
                    if(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_T){
                        t = false;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {

                }
            });
```

the error im getting is

```
Exception in thread "JNativeHook Dispatch Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = JNativeHook Dispatch Thread
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:204)
```

In case your aren't familiar with the GlobalScreen, it is basically adding a keylistener to your java program when it is not in focus and are using other things on your computer.

Is there any way i can have the JNativeHook thread access my javafx thread to reopen the program with a hotkey after it has been minimized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap them in Platform.runLater to make them run on FX thread, ie:

```
    Platform.runLater( () -> {
        if(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_ALT_L){
            alt = true;
        }
        if(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_T){
            t = true;
        }

        check();
    } );
```

Comment: Platform.runlater is the answer to everything for JavaFX ^^

Comment: Platform.runLater is the solution to any problem. Platform.runLater  is the future.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [working-with-swing](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Usage#working-with-swing) and the [SwingDispatchService.java](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/2.0/src/java/org/jnativehook/SwingDispatchService.java) class.  You should be able to implement something similar for JavaFX.

```
public class PlatformDispatchService extends AbstractExecutorService {
    private boolean running = false;

    public SwingDispatchService() {
        running = true;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        running = false;
    }

    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        running = false;
        return new ArrayList<Runnable>(0);
    }

    public boolean isShutdown() {
        return !running;
    }

    public boolean isTerminated() {
        return !running;
    }

    public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return true;
    }

    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        Platform.runLater(r);
    }
}
```